# Parsing grammar of 我想不出还会有谁

Tags: translation, grammar

我想不出还会有谁。

I don’t understand how to parse this. Is it [i][cant think of][still can][there is who]? How does that translate to “i can’t think of of anyone else”? I just see a string of verbs that don’t really logically lead to the English translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, we might say something quite similar:

> I can't think of *who* else [we] will have.

The context might be someone organizing a party.  (Note, the "we" here is grammatically required in English, but not part of the Chinese.)

So maybe it's easier to understand if it were broken down in the following way:

> 我想不出还会有谁。
>   I [我] can’t think [想不出] of who [谁] else [还] [we] will [会] have [有].
>   I can't think of who else [we] will have.

And (depending on context) it might be more natural to translate it to something simple:

> I can’t think of anyone else.

There are other ways to translate "I can’t think of anyone else" into Chinese (e.g. 我想不出其他人), and which is appropriate depends on context.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more context would make it clear.

我想不出 = I can't figure it out, I can't think, I can't imagine

还会有谁 = who else